# Conditional Sum of Data in Another List

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, calculated-column

I have two lists 'Projects' and 'Tasks' where 'Tasks' are associated with 'Projects' with a lookup column.

On the Projects list I would like to display the sum of all of the 'Actual Time' values (a column on the Tasks list) for Tasks that are associated with that Project.

Calculated columns only work within that list and lookups seem to just give me a drop down of values.

Is there any way to get this type of behaviour in SPS2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any number of ways you could do this, but all will involve some custom code:

1. You could put event receivers on the Tasks list that update an "Actual Time" field on the Projects list whenever a task changes.
2. You could write some client object model javascript on the view page that would fetch all of the calculations in real time and display them somewhere in the view.
3. You could write a web part that makes the calcualations and displays them somehow on the view page.

Each approach has its strengths and weaknnesses - which one you choose depends on the way you want to approach it, and your comfort level with the code.

Comment: I'll have to expiriment with a web part page. Those other two option sound a bit more elegant but changes to site code are highly restricted here, mostly to items I can justify having an enterprise wide impact.

Comment: assuming sandbox solutions are an option in your environment, any of these three solutions could be implemented without farm code.

Comment: If you are limited to use only "out of the box", you could create a page with both lists on. On your task list view, set it to Sum the Actual Time column. And then add a connection between the lists with the project number. That way you could get the sum pr project. But does not give an overview for all projects like you need maybe.

Comment: @AndersAune - This is the way it looks like I will be going. It provides a solid per-project view for the time being. Adding JS to the view page is also viable without seeking further approval. That will have the benefit of showing the summarized data for all projects simultaneously.